# How to send a line of code into another batch file, with a speciel character in the line

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to make a batch file that makes a batch file that makes a vbs file with code in it. But the code that tells the new batch-file that it is supposed to make a vbs-file (the "> %Popup_file_name%.vbs") does not copy over.

I have already tried to make a value

```
Set Insert=">"

Echo echo X=MsgBox("%Popup_text%",0+16,"%Popup_title%") %Insert% %Popup_file_name%.vbs >> %MalName%.bat

::But then it copies the quotation marks over.

echo X=MsgBox("%Popup_text%",0+16,"%Popup_title%") ">" %Popup_file_name%.vbs
```

This is the code

```
Echo echo X=MsgBox("%Popup_text%",0+16,"%Popup_title%") > %Popup_file_name%.vbs >> %MalName%.bat

::Here is the part that doesn't work (i have marked it with som black boxes)

Echo echo X=MsgBox("%Popup_text%",0+16,"%Popup_title%") 【﻿>】 %Popup_file_name%.vbs >> %MalName%.bat

::I expected it to just copy the line over with the "> %Popup_file_name%.vbs" but it does not.
```

Comment: But, why a `batch`, making a `batch`, making a `vbs`? Anyway, to not literally use `>` redirects, we escape them with a caret. `^>` so `echo Hello^>world>output.txt` would echo `Hello>world` to `output.txt`

Comment: Yeah i know it stupid to make a bat that make batch that make vbs, but its for a program that creates another program. Anyways thx, your the man.

Comment: In this case, `Echo Echo X=MsgBox("%Popup_text%",0+16,"%Popup_title%")^>"%Popup_file_name%.vbs">>"%MalName%.bat"` should be what you need. Although I'd prefer this syntax instead, `(Echo (Echo X=MsgBox("%Popup_text%",0+16,"%Popup_title%"^^^)^)^>"%Popup_file_name%.vbs")>>"%MalName%.bat"`.

Comment: tnx for the help